# Linq get the column Name of a datatable by using the column Index

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to be able to find one of the Column name of a datatable by using the Column index with Linq.
Example:

```
  int colindex = 2;

  Datatable: PersonInfo
  ID Name Address City State Country Zip 
  1  xx    11-23    LA  CA    USA    9123

  PersonInfo.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.field<int>(Colindex).ColumnName);

  returns Address
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you trying to use LINQ to do that? It's as easy as:

```
var columnName = PersonInfo.Columns[colindex].ColumnName;
```

You code does not work, because `Field<T>` extension method returns `T`, so `Field<int>` returns `int` and there is no way to get column name from that `int` value.

If you really have to use LINQ, you should query `DataTable.Columns` property, not the rows:

```
var columnName = PersonInfo.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ElementAt(colindex).ColumnName;
```

Comment: thanks the linq statement works, I am trying to create a linq statement that checks a few things since the app is mimic excel